# Setting MaxClientRequestBuffer for azure web app?

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure-web-app-service, limits

I want to upload a file with metadata. Unfortunately packing the file into the json is out of the question.

So, my idea to still do the upload in one call (so that it can succeed or fail atomically) is to upload the file like a normal file upload and put the metadata json into a custom header.

Now, the headers can only be 16Kb per default for the IIS (MaxClientRequestBuffer).

Since the whole app runs on Azure, I don't have a VM with a registry. So, is there another way to increase the request header limit?

Comment: As I know, we are not able to increase the header size than 16KB in Azure WebApp Service. Even if we add the headerLimits in the webconfig setting or  try to [remote](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/) the Azure Website via IIS manager to set it .

Comment: Would you mind adding this as an "answer" instead of a comment? Then I can mark it as answer and you get the credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, we are not able to increase the header size than 16KB in Azure WebApp Service currently. Even if we add the headerLimits in the webconfig setting or try to [remote](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/) the Azure Website via IIS manager to set it.